# how do I host > 100 applications each running off a specific subdomains using n application gateways?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have a VNET with an Application Gateway. This can handle upto 100 websites (in my case subdomains of customer1.mydomain.com, customer2.mydomain.com) each point to its own back-end pool.

Each application gateway handles just 1 IP address. So if I have multiple gateways I'll have multiple IPs.

If I use round robin dns customer1.mydomain.com might be directed to gateway 1 or gateway 2. Customer1s backend pool would be configured in just one of these!!

So.. fundamentally my question is, how do I host > 100 applications running off subdomains using n application gateways?

Comment: I dont follow, why cant you point all of them to a single application gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... each subdomain would have an A record which points to the IP of the gateway which knows about the specific app. Doh.

Answer (score 0):

You can point all the sites to the same Application Gateway and create Multi-site listener and the appropriate rules to achieve your ask.